# Changing a Facebook app from development to public after Facebook review

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have received Facebook approval in Facebook Developer Console, after submitting some permissions.

I've also completed all information regarding Settings and App Details, so I'm ready to make it public.
The app is developed in iOS and Android, and uses Facebook login.

My question is:
After making it public, do I have to make any changes to the Facebook Login integration in iOS and/or Android?
I don't want to break the login process at this point.

Comment: No you don't have to change anything. If you change your bundle Id then you have to update in app details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to change anything. If you change your bundle Id then you have to update in app details.

Comment: So changing the app from development to public in Facebook is transparent for mobile users?

Comment: @BernardoSalazar yes